# Remove guides and transparent background from an Illustrator document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

My Illustrator document has a transparent background and some green guidelines. How can I get rid of these and return to a normal document?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That is how a document created with a "Video" profile is set up.

- Turn the transparency grid on or off through the View menu (*View → Show/Hide Transparency Grid* or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).
- The green guides are the video safe areas and center marks, you can turn them off by enabling the Artboard Tool (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and toggling the switches in the control bar:

[image: Illustrator Artboard Tool Control Bar]

Answer (score 2):

You can remove video safe frames in artboard options dialog
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go **View > Show/Hide Transparency Grid**. (Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

I don't see any yellow guidelines in your screenshot but you can hide all guides: **View > Guides > Hide Show Guides**

Comment: This has gotten rid of the transparent background but now my whole document is white.

Comment: @Harry ...An Illustrator document is *always* transparent. It's white to *simulate* paper normally (but is actually still transparent), the video presets simply show the transparency grid by default.

Comment: @Vinny hiding guides doesn't hide the video safe area guides

Comment: @Cai Right... video guides appear green to me, so I was wondering to which yellow guides OP was referring to ^^

Comment: @Cai Sorry that's my mistake, i'm colourblind. So if they are transparent normally how do i get it back to the white and grey? do i have to turn off the video preset? if so, how would i do that?

Comment: @Harry I'm not sure what you mean, the transparency grid is white and grey, otherwise you see white, but in either case it's a display setting, neither affect your actual document

Comment: When I normally open an illustrator document, say I wanted a 1080 by 1080 document, it would come up as a white sheet and a grey background. At the moment when I create a new document it's all transparent. If I do ctrl+shift+D everything goes white instead of transparent but i still have no grey background.

Comment: @Harry Eldridge Just like Cai explained earlier, it's just because your document is created with a "Video" profile. It looks that it's not what you want really. First ask yourself what is the purpose of your document: i.e. print or web. Then, close all opened documents. Create a new document and assign the wanted profile (i.e. web), then close it. Now you have just changed the default profile. When creating a new doc, AI will assign this profile by default.

Comment: @Vinny Oh i see! I've just created a new document and changed it from custom to web and that's worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell (looking in Illustrator and this thread) there is no way to turn off video & title safe guides if you select a video profile for the document. How annoying is that? Video and title safe is an anachronism that hasn't been an issue since the demise of tube TVs. Please, Adobe (Apple and every other software developer), let the user decide.